# Pausing and resuming ARImageTrackingConfiguration() in ARKit - is it ok practise?

Tags: arkit

I am using ARKit's ARImageTrackingConfiguration() to detect reference images in AR and then place some objects into the scene using RealityKit and ARImageAnchors. Some of my app's functionality requires presenting `.sheet` upon interaction with those objects, but due to performance I would prefer pausing the AR session while the sheet is presented using

```
arView.session.pause()
```

and resume it once the .sheet is closed with

```
arView.session.run(configuration)
```

(as far as I know there's no resume function, just running it with the same config). This is simple and it works for me, but I read that Apple doesn't recommend pausing and resuming AR sessions, but this was related to ARWorldTrackingConfiguration. I wasn't able to find anything on this topic for ARImageTrackingConfiguration, so I want to ask here if it's something that I can do or it's not recommended either and I should try and avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

If you find that pausing and resuming the AR session works for your specific use case and doesn't result in any noticeable issues with tracking or performance, it might be acceptable. But I would still recommend testing thoroughly on various devices and scenarios to ensure it meets the desired performance and user experience requirements.

If you're concerned about performance, consider other optimization techniques before resorting to pausing the AR session. For instance, you can optimize the complexity of 3D models, reduce the number of objects rendered simultaneously, or implement level-of-detail techniques to manage rendering based on the object's distance from the camera.

Always prioritize a smooth and consistent user experience, and if pausing the AR session is necessary for your app's functionality, make sure to test it extensively to ensure it works reliably across different devices and usage scenarios.